# Unable to detect button press in a customized cell which is being used for two prototypes in different tables

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

So, I have two tables, table1 and table2. Table1 has a cell with reuse identifier 'feed1' and Table2 has reuse identifier 'feed'. Both these cells have a common file called feed.swift

Now, feed(Table2) is properly loaded and I can detect button press for it. But, I can't do so for feed1(Table1), however the data is loading properly. I checked the sent events by right clicking-
[image]

Here's my code for table1(where the problem lies) and table2

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell{


        if (tableView == self.Table1)
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feed1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! feed
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.username.text = username1[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
        else { 
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feed", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! feed
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.username.text = username[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
}
```

Here's my button in feed.swift file

```
@IBAction func report(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("tapped")
}
```

I can't figure out where the problem lies. While adding the button I cntrl dragged and connected to the report action that was already present. I don't really want to make another .swift file because the two prototypes are exactly the same! Thanks for helping!

Comment: If all the components on prototype cell and even the cell subclass is same, is there a reason to use separate `identifier`? plz update me if I am missing anything.

Comment: The cells are in two separate tables. I mean that's not really the issue here, because the data is getting loaded.

Comment: Can you update your question with storyboard layout. I mean both table views, prototype cells etc?